# Why do we need to set the remainder expression like this?

Tags: interpolation

I need to find interpolation polynomials and their remainder expressions satisfying the conditions $P\left(x_{i}\right)=f\left(x_{i}\right)(i=0,1,2) $ and $P^{\prime}\left(x_{1}\right)=f^{\prime}\left(x_{1}\right)$.

I wonder why I need to set the remainder expression to $R(x)=f(x)-P(x)=k(x)\left(x-x_{0}\right)\left(x-x_{1}\right)^{2}\left(x-x_{2}\right)$?

Why does the double node $x_{1}$ appear in the final remainder expression
$R(x)=\frac{1}{4 !} f^{(4)}(\xi)\left(x-x_{0}\right)\left(x-x_{1}\right)^{2}\left(x-x_{2}\right)$?

```
D[k[x] (x - x0) (x - x1)^2 (x - x2), x] /. x -> x0
D[k[x] (x - x0) (x - x1)^2 (x - x2), x] /. x -> x1
```

The calculation result of the above code only shows that the derivative value of the remainder expression at `x = x1` is 0, I want to know what causes the remainder expression to be in this form?

Comment: @xzczd Thank you very much. I think if we can explain the mechanism of these mathematical problems with MMA, it will be more conducive to the popularization of MMA.

Comment: The claim is not correct unless f(X1)=f'(x1). And this remains a math (rather than Mathematica) question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we need to set the remainder expression like this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3840654/why-do-we-need-to-set-the-remainder-expression-like-this)

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for your comments, I have deleted that duplicate post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because $R(x)=f(x)-P(x)$ and $P^{\prime}\left(x_{1}\right)=f^{\prime}\left(x_{1}\right)$, then $R^{\prime}\left(x_{1}\right)=P^{\prime}\left(x_{1}\right)-f^{\prime}\left(x_{1}\right)=0$, so $R(x)$ must have a double root at `x = 1`.

And the results of the following code confirm this, so we can set $R(x)$ to $k(x)\left(x-x_{0}\right)\left(x-x_{1}\right)^{2}\left(x-x_{2}\right)$.

```
D[k[x] (x - x0) (x - x1)^2 (x - x2), x] /. x -> x1
```

Other deeper explanations will be updated later.